# Prevent the Form from closing when ERROR occures

Tags: c#, winforms

Using winforms, when error occures, DialogResult will be Ok and the form will close, Is there a way for the form not to close ? I need `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` that part to be in my code too.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(NotERROR)
    {
        doSomething;
    } 
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
    }
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Comment: Show complete code like from `DialogResult `

Comment: `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` just closes the form when Button `Save` is clicked, thats all, there is no code after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `DialogResult.OK` only when there is no error, inside if block:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NotERROR)
    {
        DoSomething();
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    } 
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
    }
}
```